# How to register two implementations then get one in .Net Core dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have parts of my code which depend on more than one implementation of the same interface, and other parts which depend on one of the implementations.

I am registering implementations like:

```
services.AddSingleton<MyInterface, FirstImplementation>();
services.AddSingleton<MyInterface, SecondImplementation>();
```

Then getting both implementations when needed like:

```
var implementations= serviceProvider.GetServices<MyInterface>();
```

My Issue is when I need one of them, I am trying the following which returns null:

```
var firstImplementation= serviceProvider.GetService<FirstImplementation>();
```

Of course I could use:

```
var implementations= serviceProvider.GetServices<MyInterface>();
foreach (var implementation in implementations)
{
    if (typeof(FirstImplementation) == implementation.GetType())
    {
        FirstImplementation firstImplementation = (FirstImplementation)implementation;
    }
}
```

But I am thinking that I can get my `FirstImplementation`  directly somehow.

Comment: The first generic parameter does not have to be an interface. It usually is, but it doesn't need to be. You can always use the full type if the implementation difference matters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The container knows how to resolve a `FirstImplementation` when asked for the `MyInterface`, how ever is was not told how to resolve a `FirstImplementation` when asked specifically for a `FirstImplementation`.

The built-in services container is meant to serve the basic needs of the framework and most consumer applications built on it. It is bare bones and needs to be configured explicitly to behave as desired. You will need to also tell it how to get the implementations when explicitly asked for the implementations

```
//register implementations first
services.AddSingleton<FirstImplementation>();
services.AddSingleton<SecondImplementation>();

//register interfaces using factory that return implementation singleton
services.AddSingleton<MyInterface, FirstImplementation>(p => p.GetService<FirstImplementation>());
services.AddSingleton<MyInterface, SecondImplementation>(p => p.GetService<SecondImplementation>());
```

So now you can get your `FirstImplementation` directly and get the same instance

```
var firstImplementation = serviceProvider.GetService<FirstImplementation>();
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work for me because I want the same instance used by the parts depending on the interface.

Comment: @YahyaHussein If you want the same instance then why are you registering them as transient? Even with the interface every call will initialize a new instance of the implementation. You may need to clarify what it is you truly want in the question as this appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thank you for notifying me, I wrongly wrote AddTransient while simulating my problem in code, it should be a singleton, question is updated

Comment: @YahyaHussein check updated answer that should solve the problem now that it has been clarified.

Answer (score 6):

Actually what you did is not a good practice, You can create two different **interfaces** inherited from your base interface (**MyInterface**) and then register each implementation corresponding on the proper interface, After that in the part of your code which you need specific implementation you can ask from IoC go give you back specific implementation of your significant interface:

## Implementation

```
public interface IFirstImplementation:MyInterface {}
public interface ISecondImplementation:MyInterface {}
```

## Registeration

```
services.AddTransient<IFirstImplementation, FirstImplementation>();
services.AddTransient<ISecondImplementation, SecondImplementation>();
```

## Usage

```
var firstImplementation= serviceProvider.GetService<IFirstImplementation>();
```

Comment: @YahyaHussein: According to my answer one of the normal usages of IoC is to hide the implementation of each service you needed in your code, So the question is why you need both of implementation? Most of the times we need just one implemetation to run our service, By the way if you need both of implementation in same time, You can also register your implementation on MyInterface as well and get both of the by asking MyInterface from you DI Resolver, But if you want one of them the way which I expained in my answer is recommended my friend

Comment: yeah we really need to know more details in order to make a more informed answer. There are a couple of other techniques depending on whether this is a configuration issue, or if it's possible for multiple elements to need different services dynamically.

My recommendation would have been to use a factory of some kind, but the question is currently too vague to recommend that.

Comment: Well, in my case I have an implementation for logic, and the other will be registered by unit tests to hold statistics, so in unit test when a request is received I want them both to start and later I need to get the statistics for asserts.
Another valid example is two db access implementations, each deals with a different db, so a request is saved in sql and mondodb for example.

Comment: This is not a good idea. Empty interfaces created purely for the purpose of DI is a code smell and bloats code because all implementations will have a corresponding interface without even extending the base interface.

Comment: I don't see why it is a bad idea since tag interfaces are broadly used, even by Microsoft. It is a valid solution AFAIC especially if the OP has to work with the `Microsoft.Extensions.Dependencyinjection` and can't change for whatever reason (this is one conclusion of the code smell).
It will always be a cleaner and better solution than injecting the implementation class directly or having a factory that might be the perfect example of the service locator anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.Extensions.Dependencyinjection` provides the basic needs of Dependency injection, and there's other `IoC container` framework available for .NET which can solve your problem. For example, you can use [Autofac](https://autofac.org/)'s [Named Services](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#named-services) like below:

```
//registration method
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
...
builder.RegisterType<FirstImplementation>().Named<MyInterface>("first");
builder.RegisterType<SecondImplementation>().Named<MyInterface>("second");

//resolve method
var firstImplementation = container.ResolveNamed<MyInterface>("first");
```

For more complicated scenario, you can use [Keyed Services](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#keyed-services) which supports resolving with an Index and attributes.

You also need to pay attention to the [instance scope](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-scope) if uses Autofac.